# Determine UIView frame after being added to subview

Tags: objective-c, uiview, autoresize

I have custom `UIView` with autoResizeMask. Let's call it **A** view. I `initWithFrame` the **A** view and add it to subview **B**. After adding **A** view to **B**, **B** autoresizes **A** (the frame changes). To say it in other words -- **B** view fits in **A** view.

My question is, how can I determine the new frame within **A** view before showing it user?
Because I want to make some changes to **A** according new frame.

(my **A** view is `UIScrollView` subclass, and I want to set correct `contentSize`).

Comment: I do not understand. Do you like to show your view inside a UIScrollView (so it can go down or up together) or you like to set the frame when you rotate your device?

Comment: actually, i cant remember what was the problem :) but i think it was a problem, when i added one view to another view, which autoresized first view but i got wrong coordinates.